# How to impersonate user of other Azure AD App?

Tags: typescript, express, oauth-2.0, oauth, azure-active-directory

I have two different Registration Apps on Azure AD and I would like App 2 to be able to impersonate a user of App 1. My 2 apps belong to the same tenant.
I added in the permissions of App 2 the scope user_impersonation (see picture).

[image: Azure AD Scope]

Then I created an express server with passport in order to realize the oauth.

```js
const app = express()

passport.use("my-strategy", new MicrosoftStrategy({
  clientID: "my-client-id",
  clientSecret: "my-client-secret",
  callbackURL: "http://localhost:3000/auth/microsoft/callback",
  tenant: "my-tenant-id",
}, function (accessToken: string, refreshToken: string, params: any, profile: any, done: any) {
  try {
    let user = {
      accessToken: accessToken,
      refreshToken: refreshToken,
    }

    console.log(user);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error on login');
    console.log(error)

    return done(error)
  }
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send("Express Server")
});

app.get('/auth/microsoft/login',
  passport.authenticate('my-strategy'));

app.get('/auth/microsoft/callback',
  passport.authenticate('my-strategy', { failureRedirect: '/failure' }),
  function (req, res) {
    res.redirect('/success');
  });

app.get("/success", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Success");
});

app.get("/failure", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Failure");
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server running on 3000");
})
```

No problem so far, I can make my request and get an access token and a refresh token. By looking at the content of the access token I have the scope "user_impersonation".

The problem occurs when using this token. It is impossible for me to access the App 1 with this token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results successfully like below:***

I registered two Azure AD applications **`app1`** and **`app2`**.

In the **`app1`**, I exposed an API and added **scope** like below:

[image]

Now, in the **`app2`**, add the **API permission** like below:

*Go to Azure Active Directory -> App Registrations -> `app2` -> API permissions -> Add a permission -> My APIs -> **`app1`***

[image]

And **Grant the Admin consent** for the API Permissions.

Now, I generated the token for **`app2`** to access **`app1`** using Postman using below parameters:

```json
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:app2ClientID
client_secret:app2clientsecret
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:api://App1clientID/user_impersonation
redirect_uri:redirect_uri
code:code
```

The access token got generated successfully with the **`api://***/user_impersonation`** successfully like below:

[image]

When I decoded the token, the **`aud`** is `api://app1ClientId` and the **`scp`** is user_impersonation like below:

[image]

Comment: Can you access app1 with this token now ?

Comment: Yes, I am able to access the app1 with the above generated token.

Comment: Ok, I probably have a configuration problem on AD, thx for your help